Как заблюрить body
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.min.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body style="background-image: url('images/background.jpg');">

  <script src="./js/main.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>

body {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
}

Как дать blur body, filter: blur() и backdrop-filter неработает. Лучше без псевдоелеметов та без дополнительних тегов

Вы неправильно используете свойство, если оно у вас не работает.


body {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
}
<body style="background-image: url('https://cagesum.com/img/free.jpg');">

</body>



